# Filter files to translate using an attribute with Typewriter

Tags: typescript, typewriter

I would like to use Typewriter with a project where I have a lot of C# files translated in TypeScript using WebEssentials.
How can I configure the template to translate just the class files that contain an attribute this way?

```
[TypescriptModule("Palmare.Contatori")]
public class ContatoreRequest
{
    public int idProgetto { get; set; }
    public string codiceEneltel { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to filter out only class files in my `Models` namespace that have a `TypeScript` attribute. It will ignore properties with a `TypeScriptIgnore` attribute

```
${
    // Enable extension methods by adding using Typewriter.Extensions.*
    using Typewriter.Extensions.Types;

    // Uncomment the constructor to change template settings.
    bool InModelsNameSpace(Class c)
    {
        if(c.Attributes.Any(a=>a.Name == "TypeScript") && c.Namespace.Contains("Models"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool PropertyIsNotIgnored(Property p)
    {
        if(p.Attributes.Any(a => String.Equals(a.name, "TypeScriptIgnore", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || String.Equals(a.name,"NotMapped",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            return false;
        return true;

    }


    // Custom extension methods can be used in the template by adding a $ prefix e.g. $LoudName

}
module MyApp {

    $Classes($InModelsNameSpace)[
    export class $Name {
        $Properties($PropertyIsNotIgnored)[
        // $LoudName
        public $name: $Type = $Type[$Default];]
    }]


}
```